# How to copy a file.txt in different folders

Tags: unix

I have 5 folders (fld1, fld2, fld3, fld4, fld5) and I would like to copy a file called for example pippo.txt automatically in all the 5 folders using bash commands. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Copy it "automatically"?  What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in fld[1-5]
do
    cp pippo.txt $i
done
```

Or this:

```
seq 5 | xargs -n1 -I{} cp pippo.txt fld{}
```